# ios14 , TableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called

Tags: objective-c, ios14

after ios14 update
TableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called.
Running the same source in ios13 works normally

tableview A
Click to add to the parent view
[self.superview addsubview:A]
I added a table view like this
So the delegate is received from the current view
Until ios13 is normal, why not?

Answer (score 1):

There are two methodologies:

**First**

When you're using [UITableViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcontroller?language=objc) then it's automatically conformed to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols.

```
@interface UITableViewController : UIViewController;
```

**Second**

In case you're using [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview?language=objc) you have to conform it to both protocols – `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` and assign two class delegates.

```
@interface UITableView : UIScrollView;

@property(nonatomic, weak) id<UITableViewDelegate> delegate;
@property(nonatomic, weak) id<UITableViewDataSource> dataSource;
```

**If both methodologies don't work, so it's definitely a bug in iOS 14**.

About method:

```
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

Apple documentation says:

> The system doesn’t call this method if the rows in the table aren’t selectable. See [Handling Row Selection in a Table View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/handling_row_selection_in_a_table_view?language=objc) for more information on controlling table row selection behavior.

Comment: It's the same rule for all supported iOS versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is for sure an iOS 14 bug, I ran into the same issue (I believe). I think this twitter post sheds some light on the issue. Assuming your issue is the same as mine, you are now required to add subviews on cells to their contentViews. https://twitter.com/smileyborg/status/1276623198059036672

```
[tableViewCell addSubView:] - > [tableViewCell.contentView addSubView:]
```